# Существует ли более функциональная альтернатива Total Commander?

Tags: windows, файлы, файловая-система, totalcommander

Например, мне не нравится, что в Total Commander нельзя задать поведение при ошибке копирования.

Например, если сеть отвалилась, то TC будет ожидать ответа пользователя.

В том же ROBOCOPY можно задать кол-во попыток и все такое.

Comment: Эммм... про какой именно функционал идёт речь? Только про копирование или про ещё миллиард аддонов для ТС?

Comment: @donRumata, Как минимум то, что нельзя задать действия при ошибках. В ROBOCOPY можно задать кол-во попыток и временной интервал между попытками, а вот Тотал будет ждать ответа пользователя...

Comment: а там разве нет расширенных настроек копирования или плагина, который это реализует?

Comment: @donRumata Я не нашел не настроек, не плагина.

Comment: посмотри "double commander". Может там найдёшь.

Comment: @donRumata, попыток не нашел. Есть только пропуск.